# How to use single instance of Media Player on ListView item click

Tags: android, listview, singleton, android-mediaplayer

I want to play sound when user touches an item in Listview. I made list view and following is the on click implementation of item click listener.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,int pos, long id) {

 //Here I am getting getting sound bytes from raw folder with name
 // like "a"+pos and using getResourse

  mp.create(context, resid);
  mp.start();

    }
 });
```

I have not much knowledge about android's MediaPlayer

My **problem** is how should I use media player to **play single instance** of sound. I used media player (see in above code), but it play multiple instances of sound if **user clicks more than once**. If I am not wrong, it is best to call mediaplayer.create() at global level. but then how will I pass Resource id of media files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to check if MediaPlayer is null or not on each item click.

```
    if(mp!=null) {
        try{
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.w("Exception", e);
        }
    }
```

and then you can play another sound with same media player like

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this, YOUR_SOUND_FILE);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

May be this is not the best way to do this, If any one knows other way to do please update me.

thanks!

Comment: at top of class I write like this MediaPlayer mp = null. First time the code will work but when user clicks 2nd time  if statement will not work because mp is not null now, and it will not stop sound

Comment: change if condition according to your need. If you want to stop sound if media player is already playing then you have to put `mp.isPlaying()` in if condition.